# AnnoJS back button doesn't work well without specific ID

Tags: javascript, css, json, servicenow, intro.js

Having a small issue with AnnoJS and hoping someone has a solution.  We implemented AnnoJS on our ServiceNow page and it's working great, except when the element we're targeting doesn't have a specific ID (i.e. and entire row).  When we start the tour and we move onto the next element, it actually works fine:

[image]

However, when we move onto the next element and then press "Back" to come back to this element, the info box is gone:

[image]

We've found that this only happens when we're not using a specific ID on an element.  The code for this particular element looks like this:

```
           {
                target: '.row:eq(2)',
                content: "All the information about you, your new position, and your first day are here.  Make sure to check out your First Day Guide!",
                position: 'top',
                buttons: [AnnoButton.BackButton, AnnoButton.NextButton]
            },
```

The obvious fix is to give that row an ID, but ServiceNow's Service Portal doesn't give you a place to do that...

Any thoughts?